# POSTMAN sync not working behind a network proxy

Tags: proxy, postman

I'm running POSTMAN sync (sync data across devices) behind a network proxy and it is not working. Apparently it's not honoring the global proxy configuration in my system. Login in and upload is working fine. Only the sync has the issue.
I'm using 
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit
Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)
Postman version 3.2.9

I have also tried restarting and reinstalling POSTMAN with no luck.

Comment: Did you check the [proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAVJi.png) settings? Can you try using global proxy? Also see if use system proxy is set. Can you attach the Dev Tools console screenshots also?

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause is that your proxy does not allow `websocket` connections that `Postman sync` uses for data synchronization. Check for error messages in `Postman`'s `DevTools` window

[Here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1811) is a good description of how to debug this issue.